# Создание картинки из программы. Java SWING

Tags: java, swing

Есть ли способ из какого-нибудь JFrame`а сделать картинку(скриншот)? Чтобы эта картинка создавалась именно внутри программы и сохранялась на компьютере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
frame.printAll(graphics);
ImageIO.write(image , "PNG", new File("screenshot.png"));
```